# Histogram equalization for Hyperspectral Images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram

I want to apply histogram equalization for the hyperspectral images which have more than 10 bands. I want to apply histogram equalization on the hyperspectral cube. I couldn't found any method to apply histogram equalization on the hyperspectral cube. Applying histogram separately on each band and applying on complete hyperspectral cube will be same?

Comment: Are you trying to enhance the contrast of each band?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you have to apply histogram equalization to each individual band. The same parameters for the histogram equalization can be iterated over all the bands to give the hypercube an uniform equalization,like:

```
img=open_image(<your hypercube>)
img1=img.read_band(0)
img2=img.read_band(1)    #so on
img1=hist(img1)    #make your hist function A/Q your parameters
img2=hist(img2)
#so on for other bands
```

Or you can read individual bands and give them parameters according to the different histograms observed in each.